# GridSearch with Keras Neural Networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to perform parameters tuning for a neural network built with keras. This is my code with a comment on the line that causes the error:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn import grid_search
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import multiprocessing

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
import numpy as np


def tuning(X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test):

  in_size=X_train.shape[1]
  num_cores=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(in_size, input_dim=in_size, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

  batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
  epochs = [10,20]
  param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=epochs)

  k_model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, verbose=0)
  clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator=k_model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(Y_train, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=1234),
                   scoring="accuracy", verbose=100, n_jobs=num_cores)

  clf.fit(X_train, Y_train) #ERROR HERE

  print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
  print()
  print(clf.best_params_)
  print()
  print("Grid scores on development set:")
  print()
  for params, mean_score, scores in clf.grid_scores_:
    print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r"
        % (mean_score, scores.std() * 2, params))
  print()
  print("Detailed classification report:")
  print()
  print("The model is trained on the full development set.")
  print("The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.")
  print()
  y_true, y_pred = Y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
  print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
  print()
```

And this is the errors report:

```
 clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 804, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 553, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 566, in _dispatch
    job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 135, in fit
    **self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn.__call__))
TypeError: __call__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Am I missing something? The grid search goes well with random forests, svm and logistic regression. I only have problems with Neural Networks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the error indicates that the `build_fn` needs to have 2 arguments as indicated from the # of parameters from `param_grid`.

So you need to explicitly define an new function and use that as `build_fn=make_model`

```
def make_model(batch_size, nb_epoch):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(in_size, input_dim=in_size, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Also check `keras/examples/mnist_sklearn_wrapper.py` where `GridSearchCV` is used for hyper-parameter search.

Comment: No Problem. Also, now I notice that you are doing a parameter search on `batch_size` & `nb_epoch`.  Those are keras model fit parameters. In the current structure it wont work. While I think one can do that, one needs to change the wrapper code. Instead I would suggest you to use https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas where you can easily use them as hyperparameter

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe use scikit-learn 0.16 or earlier version.
I just had ran into same issue yesterday and after some workarounds I came to know that upgrading scikit-learn from 0.16 to 0.18 solves the issue.

```
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train) #SHOULD WORK with scikit-learn 0.18
```

One more thing that 0.18 differs from 0.16 is the GridSearchCV doesn't come up with `sklearn.grid_search` but with `sklearn.model_selection`

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you've solved the problem by now.

a) I guess the problem is that you're not returning the model at the end of the wrapper function `tuning()`. Use `return model`

b) `k_model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, verbose=0)` I think should be `build_fn=tuning` according to how you named your function.

c) The method's signature `def tuning(X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test)`
 isn't correct. Instead the parameters to be passed to the function, are those that need to be replaced after every iteration (i.e. the hyperparameters you specified in `param_grid`). Use `def tuning(batch_size, nb_epoch)` instead.

I hope that was helpful!