# How do I create an arrays of weights aka cheat to find optimal accuracy

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, logic, floating-accuracy

I'm a data scientist and I've been thinking for a while that when I train a model it adjusts its weights by the learning rate in direction of gradient to find the optimal accuracy of my metric... So technically all these adjusted weights can be manually generated and be used to find the optimal accuracy of my given problem.

So I tried to create a function that receives the difference of all numbers(like a learning rate for instance 0.0001) and the amount of nodes(aka size of array) in given model(can create weight possibilities for each layer though it could also be an parameter).

(For this I'm only going to be using one layer though.)

I've tried creating this myself but have failed miserably as soon as I started because the logic behind it is breaking my brain XD:

```
num = 1
lr=0.01
nodes = 100
all_posib = []
for a in range(nodes):
    llist = []
    for b in range(nodes):
        llist.append((num)*lr)
    for c in range(nodes):
        for d in range(nodes):
            llist2 = llist.copy()
            llist2[c] = ((num)*lr+(num+d)*lr)
            llist2 = [np.array([llist2])]
            all_posib.append(llist2)
```

So firstly this isn't complete but it should give an general idea of what I want to do.

Secondly this needs to somehow be vectorized or maybe there's an function that can do this better because its taking a fair amount of time to load already.

Thirdly I know this will take an heck of a long time to load the weights in any case but I'll just maybe leave it through a couple nights.

Here's a model example that I'm might use :P, I'll most like just put this in a loop and check which weight group gives the best accuracy:

```
def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu", input_shape = (train_data.shape[1], )))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam',loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mae'])
    return model

model = build_model()
model.set_weights(llist_weights)
test_mse_score, test_mae_score = model.evaluate(test_data, test_targets)
```

So if you don't want to run the above example the output that I need is basically a list of all possible weights of given nodes/size:

Example:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0.1], [0, 0, 0, 0.2], [0, 0, 0, 0.3],
 [0, 0, 0.1, 0.1], [0, 0, 0.2, 0.1], [0, 0, 0.3, 0.1],
 [0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1], [0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1],
 [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]]
```

maybe even making a list of all wanted values like [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6] which then creates all possible combinations of size 4(my logical problem was that there's more wanted values than size of array so I don't know how to logically incorporate this either)

If you could please help me out with solving this it would really be a great help(for rest of my life XD) and surely for others as well.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, conceptually, this sounds like just a duplicate of [GridSearch with Keras Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41484580/gridsearch-with-keras-neural-networks). Is that incorrect?

Comment: Have you realized that weights are continuous and this makes any brute force search problem meaningless as there are infinite possibilities?

Comment: @G.Anderson Well no girdsearch just selects different training and testing sets  but conceptually what I want to do: a neural network sets random weights on the beginning of your training and basically jumps around until it falls into an hole where the learning rate should be reduced to get to the deepest part of the hole to get its optimal accuracy... With this I basically want to find all the available holes and specifically select the deepest hole :D

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Ummm no I havent could you explain this to me, like I understand there's infinite possibilities but I already stated that it would take forever to generate all the possibilities and I'm fine with that...

Comment: Gridsearch has nothing to do with train/test split, it is for selecting the best set of hyperparameters given a list of possibilities to search over for each parameter, which sounds like what you've described

Comment: @G.Anderson yeah you're right, I just googled it :)

Answer (score 0):

I surfed around a bit more because after asking this question the answer started clearing up for me as how to approach this XD.

```
def get_all_posib_weights(nodes, lr=0.1, save=''):
    llist = (np.append(np.arange(1/lr)*lr, -np.arange(1, 1/lr)*lr))
    comb = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(llist, nodes)
    llist2 = list(comb)
    print(len(llist2))
    if len(save) > 0:
        for i, l in enumerate(llist2):
            np.save(save+'{}/{}-{}-{}.npy'.format(nodes, nodes, lr, i), l)
    return llist2Exchange/weights/'
list_weights = get_all_posib_weights(10, 0.2)
```

So this'll work and as expected it has endless possibilities, basically I plan to find the best weight set and train the model further from the chosen weight set :)
(highly impractical I know)

I'm putting this on for whomever would actually use this XD and maybe some genius will come along and improve the code :P
Adios I'll check back and let know whether it worked better than it worked with the normal training method ;)